# What would cause this reference pointer panic in fmt.Sprintf occasionally

Tags: go, panic

When I use fmt.Sprintf to format a string object in production environment，it occasionally panic like this:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x469772]

goroutine 225594643 [running]:
fmt.(*buffer).writeString(...)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/print.go:82
fmt.(*fmt).padString(0xc000112c70, 0x0, 0x7)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/format.go:110 +0x8c
fmt.(*fmt).fmtS(0xc000112c70, 0x0, 0x7)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/format.go:359 +0x61
fmt.(*pp).fmtString(0xc000112c30, 0x0, 0x7, 0x73)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/print.go:450 +0x1ba
fmt.(*pp).printArg(0xc000112c30, 0x9b4360, 0xc00193a930, 0x73)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/print.go:698 +0x843
fmt.(*pp).doPrintf(0xc000112c30, 0xaa4b6c, 0x1a, 0xc00169deb8, 0x9, 0x9)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/print.go:1030 +0x15a
fmt.Sprintf(0xaa4b6c, 0x1a, 0xc00169deb8, 0x9, 0x9, 0xc001edced0, 0xa)
        /home/compile/makepkg_go/go/src/fmt/print.go:219 +0x66
code.aliyun.com/re-audio/engines/simplestatisticengine.AudioCountRun(0xc001ca7a00, 0x14, 0x0, 0x7, 0xa9
8fec, 0xa, 0xa98dd0, 0xa, 0xc0018e329b, 0x5, ...)
        /home/compile/makepkg/re-audio/engines/simplestatisticengine/sse.go:253 +0x384
created by code.aliyun.com/re-audio/audioprocessor.(*AudioClips).clipsStatistic
        /home/compile/makepkg/re-audio/audioprocessor/audio-clips.go:549 +0x3a0
```

relative code is :

```
    func AudioCountRun(
        organization, appId, serviceId,
        pattern, channel, soundproperty string, riskType int,
        riskLevel, reqId string) {
        if len(organization) == 0 || len(appId) == 0 || len(serviceId) == 0 || len(pattern) == 0 || len(channel) == 0 || len(soundproperty) == 0 || riskType < 0 || len(riskLevel) == 0 {
            return
        }
        if serviceId != "POST_AUDIO" {
            return
        }
        curTime := time.Now().Format(layout)
        key := fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s@%s@%s@%s@%s@%s@%d@%s",
            curTime, organization, appId,
            serviceId, pattern, channel,
            soundproperty, riskType, riskLevel)
        batchstatistic.Add(audioMapName, key, 1)
        ilog.LogReq(ilog.LL_INFO, "SimpleStatisticEngine.AudioCountRun.Add", reqId, fmt.Sprintf("(audioMapName=%s,key=%s)", audioMapName, key))
    }
```

This problem is difficult to repeat. I guess there's something wrong with the "appId" parameter in AudioCountRun. Uncertainly, the type of appId was right, but its data was wrong.
In what direction should I look for the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Which Sprintf  is causing the problem? What is audioMapName?

Comment: this line : key := fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s@%s@%s@%s@%s@%s@%d@%s"....  audioMapName is a string object.

Answer (score 0):

Should see this issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39587

there are data race on `audioMapName` or `key` in your program

Comment: thx, I found appId would be modified by other goroutine

Comment: appId was passed by value, it's not the reason.